# Is it a bad practice to use sleep() in a web server in production?

Tags: python, django

I'm working with Django1.8 and Python2.7.

In a certain part of the project, I open a socket and send some data through it. Due to the way the other end works, I need to leave some time (let's say 10 miliseconds) between each data that I send:

```
   while True:
       send(data)
       sleep(0.01)
```

So my question is: is it considered a bad practive to simply use `sleep()` to create that pause? Is there maybe any other more efficient approach?

UPDATED: 
The reason why I need to create that pause is because the other end of the socket is an external service that takes some time to process the chunks of data I send. I should also point out that it doesnt return anything after having received or let alone processed the data. Leaving that brief pause ensures that each chunk of data that I send gets properly processed by the receiver.

EDIT: changed the sleep to 0.01.

Comment: `http` connections are usually stateless, so a sleep is a bit meaningless without some context. What exactly are you doing that requires it?

Comment: Is there any limitation to make that part asynchronous?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is bad practice and an anti-pattern. You will tie up the "worker" which is processing this request for an unknown period of time, which will make it unavailable to serve other requests. The classic pattern for web applications is to service a request as-fast-as-possible, as there is generally a fixed or max number of concurrent workers.  While this worker is continually `sleep`ing, it's effectively out of the pool.  If multiple requests hit this endpoint, multiple workers are tied up, so the rest of your application will experience a bottleneck.  Beyond that, you also have potential issues with database locks or race conditions.

The standard approach to handling your situation is to use a task queue like *Celery*.  Your web-application would tell *Celery* to initiate the task and then quickly finish with the request logic.  *Celery* would then handle communicating with the 3rd party server.  *Django* works with *Celery* exceptionally well, and there are many tutorials to help you with this.

If you need to provide information to the end-user, then you can generate a unique ID for the task and poll the result backend for an update by having the client refresh the URL every so often.  (I think *Celery* will automatically generate a guid, but I usually specify one.)

Answer (score 3):

Like most things, short answer: it depends.

Slightly longer answer:
If you're running it in an environment where you have many (50+ for example) connections to the webserver, all of which are triggering the sleep code, you're really not going to like the behavior.  I would strongly recommend looking at using something like celery/rabbitmq so Django can dump the time delayed part onto something else and then quickly respond with a "task started" message.

If this is production, but you're the only person hitting the webserver, it still isn't great design, but if it works, it's going to be hard to justify the extra complexity of the task queue approach mentioned above.